# Problems querying

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, xml-namespaces

I'm trying to query the following XML the way I always do, but due to its declaration and the empty "NextQuantity" - "NextDate" fields, I'm having troubles querying the XML.

What's the right way to do this?

Thank you.

```
<StocksResp xmlns="http://xxxxxx" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <Stocks>
    <Stock>
      <Sku>30101.06-L</Sku>
      <Quantity>247610</Quantity>
      <NextQuantity1>15243</NextQuantity1>
      <NextDate1>2019-02-27</NextDate1>
      <NextQuantity2 i:nil="true" />
      <NextDate2 />
      <NextQuantity3 i:nil="true" />
      <NextDate3 />
      <NextQuantity4 i:nil="true" />
      <NextDate4 />
      <NextQuantity5 i:nil="true" />
      <NextDate5 />
      <NextQuantity6 i:nil="true" />
      <NextDate6 />
    </Stock>
    <Stock>
      <Sku>30101.06-M</Sku>
      <Quantity>241606</Quantity>
      <NextQuantity1 i:nil="true" />
      <NextDate1 />
      <NextQuantity2 i:nil="true" />
      <NextDate2 />
      <NextQuantity3 i:nil="true" />
      <NextDate3 />
      <NextQuantity4 i:nil="true" />
      <NextDate4 />
      <NextQuantity5 i:nil="true" />
      <NextDate5 />
      <NextQuantity6 i:nil="true" />
      <NextDate6 />
    </Stock>
 </Stocks>
  <Count>4837</Count>
  <Currency i:nil="true" />
  <Language>ES</Language>
  <ErrorCode i:nil="true" />
  <ErrorMessage i:nil="true" />
</StocksResp>
```

===============================================

```
DECLARE @xml XML
SELECT @xml = x.y FROM OPENROWSET (BULK 'file.xml',SINGLE_BLOB) as x(y)

SELECT  
   x.y.value('Sku[1]','varchar(15)'),
   x.y.value('Quantity[1]','int'),
   x.y.value('NextDate1[1]','varchar(20)'),
   x.y.value('NextQuantity1[1]','int'),
   'mr'
FROM   @xml.nodes('Stocks/Stock') x(y)
```

Comment: Unclear what you are asking `<NextQuantity1>15243</>` is not valid XML. Is that just a mistake in the Q? What are the desired results? What problem are you having? Definitely looks like you should be using `WITH XMLNAMESPACES ` and including `StocksResp` in the path

Comment: Martin, sorry, it was a mistyping. I already corrected. Anyway, thank you for your help too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might this help?

```
DECLARE @xml XML=
N'<StocksResp xmlns="http://xxxxxx" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <Stocks>
    <Stock>
      <Sku>30101.06-L</Sku>
      <Quantity>247610</Quantity>
      <NextQuantity1>15243</NextQuantity1>
      <NextDate1>2019-02-27</NextDate1>
      <NextQuantity2 i:nil="true" />
      <NextDate2 />
      <NextQuantity3 i:nil="true" />
      <NextDate3 />
      <NextQuantity4 i:nil="true" />
      <NextDate4 />
      <NextQuantity5 i:nil="true" />
      <NextDate5 />
      <NextQuantity6 i:nil="true" />
      <NextDate6 />
    </Stock>
    <Stock>
      <Sku>30101.06-M</Sku>
      <Quantity>241606</Quantity>
      <NextQuantity1 i:nil="true" />
      <NextDate1 />
      <NextQuantity2 i:nil="true" />
      <NextDate2 />
      <NextQuantity3 i:nil="true" />
      <NextDate3 />
      <NextQuantity4 i:nil="true" />
      <NextDate4 />
      <NextQuantity5 i:nil="true" />
      <NextDate5 />
      <NextQuantity6 i:nil="true" />
      <NextDate6 />
    </Stock>
 </Stocks>
  <Count>4837</Count>
  <Currency i:nil="true" />
  <Language>ES</Language>
  <ErrorCode i:nil="true" />
  <ErrorMessage i:nil="true" />
</StocksResp>';
```

-You need to declare the default namespace. You would not need to declare the namespace `i`...

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'http://xxxxxx','http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' AS i)
SELECT 
       @xml.value(N'(/StocksResp/Count/text())[1]',N'int') AS StockResp_Count
      ,@xml.value(N'(/StocksResp/Currency/text())[1]',N'int') AS StockResp_Currency 
      ,st.value(N'(Sku/text())[1]',N'nvarchar(max)') AS Stock_Sku
      ,st.value(N'(Quantity/text())[1]',N'int') AS Stock_Quantity
      ,st.value(N'(NextQuantity1/text())[1]',N'int') AS Stock_NextQuantity1
      ,st.value(N'(NextDate1/text())[1]',N'date') AS Stock_NextDate1
      ,st.value(N'(NextQuantity2/text())[1]',N'int') AS Stock_NextQuantity2
      ,st.value(N'(NextDate2/text())[1]',N'date') AS Stock_NextDate2
      ,st.value(N'(NextQuantity3/text())[1]',N'int') AS Stock_NextQuantity3
      ,st.value(N'(NextDate3/text())[1]',N'date') AS Stock_NextDate3
      ,st.value(N'(NextQuantity4/text())[1]',N'int') AS Stock_NextQuantity4
      ,st.value(N'(NextDate4/text())[1]',N'date') AS Stock_NextDate4
      ,st.value(N'(NextQuantity5/text())[1]',N'int') AS Stock_NextQuantity5
      ,st.value(N'(NextDate5/text())[1]',N'date') AS Stock_NextDate5
      ,st.value(N'(NextQuantity6/text())[1]',N'int') AS Stock_NextQuantity6
      ,st.value(N'(NextDate6/text())[1]',N'date') AS Stock_NextDate6
FROM   @xml.nodes('/StocksResp/Stocks/Stock') A(st);
```

Some remarks:

It is a very bad habit to *name-number* elements (Date1, Date2 and so on). If you can change this, you should use a nested set of elements and number them eiter by their position or with an attribute like

```
<Next index="1">
   <Date>2018-01-01</Date>
   <Quantity>1</Quantity>
</Next>
[... more of them ...]
```

you can see, that I read the *just-once* values directly from the variable, while the repeating elements are taken from a derived table by `.nodes()`.

Comment: Thank you, Shnugo. It works fine. I've learned something new today thanks to you. Unfortunately, the XML is not mine, it's from one of our providers, so this is not in my hands.